# Keyset/seek pagination and filter by search term

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

Using table
`products(id, title, price, category_id)`

How to filter product by title, price, category_id, pieces and retrieve second page using keyset/seek pagination? a page have 10 items

https://blog.jooq.org/2016/08/10/why-most-programmers-get-pagination-wrong/

SQL using offset pagination will be

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE title like '%search_term%' AND price > 100 AND price < 400 AND category_id=11
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Results can be in this order

```
(id=23, title='Some text', price=354, category_id=11)
(id=41, title='Big text', price=333, category_id=11)
(id=43, title='big big text', price=333, category_id=11)
(id=38, title='A text', price=288, category_id=11)
(id=11, title='text', price=200, category_id=11)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### A pure SQL solution for keyset pagination

The first thing to understand when talking about keyset pagination is that there's no such thing as the "second" page. There are only "next pages" given a "current page". In your case, the current page would be the one that ends on:

```
(id=11, title='text', price=200, category_id=11)
```

So, the next page would be the one that has a `(price, id) < (200, 11)` (current price, id). If this query produces your *first page*:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products
-- "Ordinary predicates"
WHERE title LIKE '%search_term%' 
AND price > 100 AND price < 400 
AND category_id = 11
ORDER BY price DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Then, this query will produce your *next page*

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products
-- "Ordinary predicates"
WHERE title LIKE '%search_term%' 
AND price > 100 AND price < 400 
AND category_id = 11
-- "Keyset pagination predicate"
AND (price, id) < (200, 11)
ORDER BY price DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Alternatively, that predicate could be expanded to this:

```sql
-- "Keyset pagination predicates"
AND (price < 200 OR price = 200 AND id < 11)
```

Or even to this:

```sql
-- "Keyset pagination predicate"
AND price <= 200
AND (price < 200 OR price = 200 AND id < 11)
```

Depending on the database, the three different predicates may perform differently

#### A jOOQ solution

Since you're referencing the jOOQ blog, here's how you would write the query on the second page using jOOQ:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(PRODUCTS)
   .where(PRODUCTS.TITLE.like("%search_term%")
   .and(PRODUCTS.PRICE.gt(100))
   .and(PRODUCTS.PRICE.lt(400))
   .and(PRODUCTS.CATEGORY_ID.eq(11))
   .orderBy(PRODUCTS.PRICE.desc(), PRODUCTS.ID.desc())
   .seek(200, 11) // Automatic generation of keyset pagination predicates
   .limit(10)
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks. How to understand this predicate `(price, id) < (200, 11)` ?

Comment: @tewumat: I have foreseen your question and explained it in my answer, which I invite you to re-read. When you come across the word "expanded", read it as ***expanded***